# MLE of $\theta$ for a log-normal distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, maximum-likelihood

I have the pdf of a log-normal distribution:

$$ f(y;\theta)= \frac {1}{y\sqrt{2\pi\theta}}\exp \left(-{\frac {(\log y)^2}{ 2\theta}}\right)$$
for $y>0$ and $\theta>0$ and $f(y; \theta) = 0$ otherwise.

and assuming that $E(\log Y_i) = 0$ and $\operatorname{var}(\log Y_i) = \theta$

I need help finding the maximum likelihood estimator of $\theta$ so I can find the expected information and the approx standard error.

Can I please get some help on how to get started?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the log likelihood given $n$ observations is
$$l(\theta) = \log \prod_{i=1}^n f(y_i;\theta) \propto - \sum_{i=1}^n \log y_i - \frac{n}{2} \log \theta - \frac{1}{2\theta}\sum_{i=1}^n \log^2 y_i$$
Derive w.r.t $\theta$ and set it to zero to get the first order condition:
$$l'(\theta) = - \frac{n}{2\hat{\theta}} + \frac{1}{2\hat{\theta}^2} \sum_{i=1}^n \log^2 y_i = 0$$
or
$$ n = \frac{1}{\hat{\theta}} \sum_{i=1}^n \log^2 y_i$$
This means that the MLE of $\theta$ is
$$ \hat{\theta} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \log^2 y_i$$

Comment: Thanks Ahmad. I got a slightly different answer can you please let me know where I got wrong: $$l'(\theta) = - \frac{n}{2\hat{\theta}} - \frac{1}{2\hat{\theta}} \sum_{i=1}^n (logy_i)^2 = 0$$

Comment: your second term should contain $\theta^2$ not $\theta$

Comment: Also you should have a minus sign on the second term after the derivative is performed.

Comment: yeah as @Chinny84 mentions, you should have a - sign

Comment: Thank you! I made a silly mistake in my calculation. I've got the same now